# execute a function (e.g. finally) before then/catch in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing in `electron`. My project has the following snippet of code:

```
showLoading('confirm')
    api.deliveries.create(NewDelivery.createDelivery()).then((insertId) => {
        NewDelivery.back()
        showAlert('alert-success', 'Delivery Saved!', 'Delivery ID: ' + insertId)
    }).catch((error) => {
        eid('message').innerText = 'Delivery not saved. Try again later or contact the developer'
        throw error
    }).finally(() => {
        finishLoading('confirm')
        $('#confirmModal').modal('hide')
    })
```

When the block executes successfully, `NewDelivery.back` is called, which removes the elements with ids 'confirm' and 'confirmModal' from the `DOM`, breaking my application. My question is, is there a way to execute the `finally` block **before** either `then` or `catch` is called? Thank you.

Comment: What is element with ids ?

Comment: What happens if you put `then` (containing the breaking `back`)) after `finally`?

Comment: Yeah, that works. I didn't think of that. Is there a way to mark a comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to reorder the chain...

```js
Promise.resolve('do somthing')
  .finally(() => console.log('finally called'))
  .then(() => console.log('successfull'))
  .catch(() => console.log('error!'))
```